Batch "echo|set/p=" adds a space at the end of the line
Ran into a bit of trouble when using "echo|set/p=" to print lines without carriage return and line feed. Namely that I get an unwanted space at the end of the text I create and I haven't found a way to remove it.
Example:
Running echo TEST>>TEST.TXT in batch command line gives a file which contains TEST followed by a carriage return and a line feed.
Running echo|set/p=TEST>>TEST.TXT in batch command line gives a file which contains TEST followed by a single space character, but no carriage return or line feed.
Where does this mysterious space come from and is there any way to remove it?

Instead, you should use
<nul set /p "=Test" >> test.txt

The differences are:

<nul instead of echo | nul simply is an empty redirect, but ECHO with a pipe creates two new cmd.exe instances
Using a pipe creates some magic reorder of commands on both sides
Use quotes to avoid unwanted spaces or problems with special characters


Thank you, works like a charm.
As someone who generally only does bash scripts, batch always is annoying because of its limited functions.

@WeirdGuy I don't use batch or Windows either, but I like the challenge of solving problems with batch that would be easy in Bash.

This whole question originated from imitating bash functionality with batch out of necessity.

You may find this DosTips topic on how to output text without linefeed helpful.
